# Provide option to download file using aiohttp server

Tags: python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

How would it be possible to serve a downloadable file using aiohttp / asyncio?

I'm using:

```
async def route_function(request):
    return web.Response(body=b"Test")
```

to just simply serve content.

Comment: What do you mean by *downloadable*? Should browser open a dialog box for selecting saving location?

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov Nope, just to immediately download.

Comment: Do you want to download relative small file or it's size if about 500 MB long?

Answer (score 2):

> The Content-Disposition header can indicate that the response body is
>   to be downloaded as an actual file, as opposed to displayed in the
>   browser. [[*]](http://www.symkat.com/force-download-with-http-headers)

- `Content-Disposition: Attachment`
- `Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=some_file.xyz` with filename

With aiohttp:

```
from aiohttp import MultiDict

async def route_function(request):
    return web.Response(
        headers=MultiDict({'Content-Disposition': 'Attachment'}),
        body=b"Test"
    )
```